# spring-boot mix java-scala app - not able to find correct objectmapper

Tags: java, spring, scala, spring-boot

I am hitting weird issue with spring-boot, mixed java-scala web app. jar is created as `org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher`(layout=ZIP) jar so I can use loader.path to load external libraries. I have registered `DefaultScalaModule` from fasterxml jackson-scala module with spring-boot via `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`. I created an uber jar with spring-boot-maven plugin. I deploy my app with `java -Dloader.path=xxx -jar myspringbootscala.jar` . It deploys and runs perfectly everytime on my mac os but on linux I am hitting following errors "randomly" most of the time. Surprisingly it works once in while as well!

Error #1:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1446079480082,
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
  "message": "Could not read document: Instantiation of [simple type, class com.mycomp.DataRequest] value failed: null; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Instantiation of [simple type, class com.mycomp.DataRequest] value failed: null",
  "path": "/myspringbootapp/v2/api/scdata"
}
```

If I don't get above then I get following:

Error #2 This one is not as dreaded as above. It's a fasterxml scala ojbectmapper issue

```
29 Oct 2015 17:04:17.000 [http-nio-8280-exec-1] ERROR c.x.i.i.ControllerInterceptor- Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt(BoxesRunTime.java:106)
    at scala.Tuple2._1$mcI$sp(Tuple2.scala:19)
    at com.mycomp.validator.DataRequestValidator$$anonfun$validate$1.apply(DataRequest\Validator.scala:94) //This line is simply boxing java.lang.String to scala.Int but runtime thinks it needs to convert java.lang.String to java.lang.Integer! I have `import scala.collection.JavaConversions._` on this class.
```

Again things same jar works perfectly on my mac with same command line options and classpath. Both scala and java controllers (databinding) works without any issue. But on linux only java controllers (databinding) works and with scala I get one of the above error at different times. As I mentioned it does work on linux as well sometime.

There's most likely some external factor that causing this but I can't figure out what it is?

**EDIT:**
I think when I run my app on linux spring-boot is not picking up scala object mapper that I set and hence 400
Here's how I set my object mapper

```
@Component
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebMvcCustomConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

 @Bean
  public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter customJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter scalaJsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper scalaObjectMapper = new ScalaObjectMapper();
    //scalaObjectMapper.enable(features)
    //objectMapper.registerModule(new DefaultScalaModule());
    scalaObjectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    scalaJsonConverter.setObjectMapper(scalaObjectMapper);
    return scalaJsonConverter;
  }

  @Override 
  public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

    super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    //converters.add(0, customJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    Iterator<HttpMessageConverter<?>>  itr = converters.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
      HttpMessageConverter<?> conv = itr.next();
      if(conv instanceof org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter){
        itr.remove(); //my try-error attempt. doesnt work.
      }
    }
    converters.add(0, customJackson2HttpMessageConverter()); //Replacing with my own customJackson2HttpMessageConverter
    for(HttpMessageConverter<?> conv: converters){
      System.out.println("httpconverter: "+ conv.getClass());
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: So you mixed scalla controllers and java controller in the same project, which part is in scala and which in java (i mean your code)? I have a similar project and it works ok, but everything is in scala

Comment: I have different parent package hierarchy for scala and java. i.e. com.mycomp.scala and com.mycomp.java. Java and scala controllers are separate.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure of root cause why things were working on local mac and not on remote linux box despite of having same jvm and scala libraries. Here's what I did that "fixed" above issues. In Maven, I explicitly set following scala deps

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalap</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

Updates fasterxml-scala version from 2.6.1 to 2.6.3

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
            <!-- exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions -->
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Class that was giving me `java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer` I removed JavaConversion and changed everything into scala. voila! Still don't know the root cause so feel free to add any insights.